# How to determine if a column in a datagrid is sorted or not.

Tags: dojo, grid

I would like to click on the header of a dojo data grid and retrieve information such as if it is sorted and what direction is it sorted in, the column index, and the column name.  Has anyone done this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the getSortProps function in dojox.grid.Datagrid. Calling this function will return a JSON with the field that is being currently sorted and what direction. You can get the index by calling the getSortIndex function.  Don't know how to get the name off the top of my head